# How to get a set of values from a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, set

I have this Pandas dataframe with rows and columns having the same titles which are names of people: Alex, Bob, Cynthia and cells being the number of times they have met, where `-1` means that the cell is diagonal.

|  | Alex | Bob | Cynthia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | -1 | 2 | 3 |
| Bob | 1 | -1 | 2 |
| Cynthia | 2 | 2 | -1 |

Is there any elegant way to get a set of numeric values that are in the cells? So, for this table I want `values = {1, 2, 3}`. So far I can think of only iterating over the whole table in a nested-loop fashion and putting everything in a set.

Is there any other way of getting this set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
set(df.values.flatten())
```

And to exclude -1:

```
set(df.values.flatten()).difference([-1])
```

Comment: What is the table contains the names of the columns as values and they also get into the set being string. Is there any way to filter out non-integer values?

Comment: The cleanest would be to drop this row using `loc`/`iloc` first. For instance if first row: `df.iloc[1:].values...`